# Why is this JPA 2.0 entity merged only after a find()?

Tags: java, jpa

My application creates an Object in a first transaction. Then, another transaction tries to update the database with those changes, but instead of updating the entity, a new one is created. If I do a `find` before `merge`, then the right record is updated. Why is that?

This is the entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyObject implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MY_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MY_SEQ", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ_GEN", allocationSize = 1)
    Long id;

    String stuff;
    String businessKey;

    // getter, setters, hashcode, equals (using "businessKey")
}
```

This the record is created and updated: (see below for `create` and `update`):

```
MyObject obj = bean.create();
bean.update(obj);
```

But as said before, this fails to update the first record, it creates another one instead!

If I try to `find` this entity before the merge operation (without even doing anything with the returned object), then it's correctly updated (see below for `create` and `findAndUpdate`):

```
MyObject obj = bean.create();
bean.findAndUpdate(obj);
```

Here is the EJB:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Stateless
public class Bean {

final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Bean.class);

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MYUNIT")
EntityManager em;

public MyObject create(){

    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.businessKey = "some string";

    em.persist(obj);

    LOGGER.debug("MyObject.id: {}", obj.id); // eg. 100

    return obj;
}

public void update(MyObject obj){

    obj.stuff = "some stuff";

    MyObject merged = em.merge(obj);

    LOGGER.debug("obj.id: {}", obj.id); // still 100
    LOGGER.debug("merged.id: {}", merged.id); // new id: 101!

}

public void findAndUpdate(MyObject obj){

    obj.stuff = "some stuff";

    em.find(MyObject.class, obj.id); // doing nothing with the returned MyObject

    MyObject merged = em.merge(obj);

    LOGGER.debug("obj.id: {}", obj.id); // still 100
    LOGGER.debug("merged.id: {}", merged.id); // still 100!

}
}
```

Comment: Which jpa implementation youre using?

Comment: I'm running on JBoss EAP 6.1, with its Hibernate 4.2.0.Final module.

Comment: Can you check if the object that you are trying to merge has `Id` value populated correctly or not? If it doesn't have `id` field populated then Hibernate will treat it as new object and inserts new record in DB else it should update existing record in DB. On a different note, I see the `save(MyObject obj)` and `update(Message message)` methods are working on different class types. Is that correct?

Comment: Fixed the references to another object, that was a copy/paste error. The object has indeed its id correctly populated: after persist, its id has for instance value `123`. After merge, its id is still `123`, but another record with id `124` is created in the db, containing the updated fields ("stuff").

Comment: @Virginie Not sure if you have performed sysout just before calling `merge` method or immediately after persist. Do you see the `id` is `123` just before merge? If not, you may want to try it and see.

Comment: Ca we see hascode and equals impl please ? Otherwise just try to comment them out and run your test again

Comment: @Gab: I tried with different implementations of `equals` (not at all, based on `id`, based on `businessKey`) with the same results.

Comment: @Madhusudana Reddy Sunnapu: updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be outside the given code. I am guessing the MyObject instance you are passing on to update() was created by either calling `new` or through some sort of deserialization, like from JSON for example. The entity manager instance `em` (usually created at request start and destroyed after it's end) only contains entities that have been loaded by it. These entities are compared by reference when they are looked-up and not tested for key equality. In essence, using `contains`, you are asking it "Are you tracking this instance of my object?", and you can have many instances of an object that are of the same class with the same primary key, but the entity manager does not track them unless you received that reference from it.

Answer (score -1):

That is the way it works.
Creating a new Entity i.e new MyObject()  means that u want to add a row in the DB.
Whereas when u find the object it becomes a managed object in JPA and any changes to it within the transaction would be updated.
And outside the transaction if u make changes and merge it, it would be updated as that entity became managed entity when you used em.find(MyObject.class) .

For Example:

```
 MyObject obj = em.find(MyObject.class,PK);
 obj.setObjName("abc");
```

This would be updated in the DB,  even if u don't call em.merge(obj).

Comment: This is not really answering the question which is why a new transient instance made persistent in T1 is not recognised as a persistent but detached entity in T2.